# VS Code: watch typescript on save file

Tags: typescript, task, visual-studio-code, tsc, tsd

In Visual Studio Code, I have the following code in code in tsconfig.json

```
{
    "version": "1.6.0",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "watch": true,
        "experimentalAsyncFunctions": true,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    ...
}
```

As you can see, the `watch` option is at true. Well, look like this isn't enough to compile a .ts file to .js just like the atom-typescript does. Basically, the new compiled .js should be in the same directory of the .ts file when saving the .ts.

Also, I'd like avoid using gulp in my root project, since I already use a gulpfile.coffee for other means. Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 3):

With the most recent versions of VS Code 1.7.2 and Typescript 2.0.10 you just need to have the following code in `.vscode/tasks.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-w", "-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "isWatching": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
}
```

The `watch` option in `tsconfig.json` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define a tasks.json in the .vscode folder looking something like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "args": ["HelloWorld.ts"],
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

you can find more information about it here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript